# How to reduce the size of gutter within a div that creates two columns?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, css-tables

I've read countless posts on this type of topic (although no one seems to have specifically the exact same question) but any attempts I've made have failed.  I've added code to my site to list items in a similar format to a table, without including a table since it gets cut off on mobile sites; whereas a 'div' style table does not.

Currently, the column on the right is forcing the text to wrap within the 'cell' we'll call it, due to the fact that it's way over to the right of the screen, instead of utilizing the space effectively.  To put it in perspective, I'm looking to give the second column 70% of a 100% size table if this was a table. It should only be about 20-40px away from the left column, whereas now there is about 40-50% of white space between the two columns.

Here is my code:

```
<style>
.list_item1 {
    display: inline-block;
    display:list-item;
    list-style-type: disc;
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin: 5px;

}
.list_item2 {
    display: inline-block;
    display:list-item;
    list-style-type: disc;
    list-style-position: inside;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: auto; 
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px;

}
#wraplist {
    width:100%;
    column-count:2;
    column-gap:10px;
    -moz-column-count:2;
    -moz-column-gap:10px;
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    -webkit-column-gap:10px;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

With the HTML as:

```
<div id="wraplist">
<div class="list_item1">A</div>
<div class="list_item1">B</div>
<div class="list_item1">C</div>
<div class="list_item1">D</div>
<div class="list_item1">E</div>
<div class="list_item2">F</div>
<div class="list_item2">G</div>
<div class="list_item2">H</div>
<div class="list_item2">I is a really long statement</div>
<div class="list_item2">J is a really long statement</div>
</div>
```

It looks odd to state 100% for the width of list_item2 but that's the only way I'm able to 'sort of' fit the two long statements in their designated area.  There is still text wrapping though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to set different width for columns, that's why the big white space is there. However, there are other solutions for your problem:

check out this [**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/75Qvz/)

the HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="wraplist1">
    <div class="list_item1">A</div>
    <div class="list_item1">B</div>
    <div class="list_item1">C</div>
    <div class="list_item1">D</div>
    <div class="list_item1">E</div>
  </div>
  <div id="wraplist2">
    <div class="list_item2">F</div>
    <div class="list_item2">G</div>
    <div class="list_item2">H</div>
    <div class="list_item2">I is a really long statement</div>
    <div class="list_item2">J is a really long statement</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#wraplist1, #wraplist2 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: normal;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

#wraplist1{
    width: 20%;
}

#wraplist2{
    width: 50%;
}

.list_item1 {
    display:list-item;
    list-style-type: disc;
    list-style-position: inside;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.list_item2 {
    display:list-item;
    list-style-type: disc;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Comment: i dont know what would you like to do with the text in the 2nd 'column' when it reaches the right-border. do you want to hide the overflowed text?

Comment: Due to how much information I provided in my response, I posted it as an answer.  To answer your question though, the overflow text originally was hiding so it looked cut off, but I wanted it to wrap, or ideally fill the space correctly so that wrapping wasn't required.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for providing this!  Late last night I made a breakthrough with the formatting.  This is what I ended up doing:

```
<style>

.div-table{
  display:table;         
  width:auto;         
}
.div-table-row{
  display:table-row;
  clear:both;
}
.div-table-col{
  float:left;
  display:table-column;          
}
ul#list_style {
   list-style-type: disc;
}
</style>
```

Then within the body:

```
<div class="div-table">
    <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-col">
        <ul id="list-style">
             <li>A</li>
             <li>B</li>
             <li>C</li> 
             <li>D</li>
             <li>E</li> 
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="div-table-col">
        <ul id="list-style">
             <li>F</li>
             <li>G</li>
             <li>H</li>  
             <li>I</li>
             <li>J</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style='clear:both;'></div>
```

Now the spacing between the two divs is aesthetically pleasing to the eye :)